# Weierstrass M-test: Do the terms of the M-series have to be the same constants?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Do the terms of the M-series in [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) have to be the same constants? Or can the $M_n$s be anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "the same constants"? $ M_1$ is usually not equal to $ M_2$, for example.

Comment: Do the $M_n$s have to be the same number?

Comment: The formulation speaks of $M_n$s being a series of constants, which is not very good wording, because "constant" can be interpreted to mean "they are the same constant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the numbers $ M_n $ are allowed to be different. (In fact, if they were all the same positive number, the condition $\sum M_n < \infty $ would not be satisfied.)